# Homology of koszul complex is finitely generated?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

$A$ a local ring and $a_{1}$, ..., $a_{n}$ elements in its maximal ideal, $M$ a finitely generated $A$-module. In this case apparently the homologies from the Koszul complex are finitely generated as $A$-module. Is there a simple explanation for this? Or is it some deep result? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your local rings are Noetherian it's obvious. The Koszul complex
consists of finitely generated free modules and the homology
modules are subquotients of it so also finitely generated.

For non-Noetherian rings it's not true, even when $n=1$. In
this case the $H_1$ is the annihilator of $a_1$ which may not
be finitely generated. As an example consider the quotient
of $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ by the ideal generated by all the
$x_i x_j$. The annihilator of $x_1$ is the
non-finitely generated maximal ideal.

Answer (score 5):

Take $A=k[x_1,x_2,\dots]/(x_ix_j:1\leq i,j)$ be the quotient of the ring of polynomials in countably many indeterminates by the ideal generated by quadratic monomials, and let $M=A$ and $a_1=x_1$.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the [definition I know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koszul_complex), it seems to be because all the groups in the Koszul complex are finitely generated as $A$-modules, being explicitely constructed as sums of tensor products of $M$!

Comment: Unless you assume the ring is neotherian, there *is* something to prove, no?

Comment: Thanks! I misread the question as being about *finitely presented* modules. As Robin Chapman correctly says, the question is stated needs some additional assumptions!